# Boolean value variable case

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner in Python trying to study from YouTube, Mosh hamedani 6 hour course. I got stuck on car game, code is listed below:

```
{command = ""
started = False
while True:
    command = input('> ').lower()
    if command == 'start':
        if started:
            print('car is already started') 
        else:
            started = True
            print("Car has started")
    elif command == 'stop':
        if not started:
            print('car is already stopped !')
        else:
            started = False
            print('Car has stopped')
    elif command == 'help':
        print("""
start - to start a car
stop  - to stop a car
quit  - to quit a game
        """)
    elif command == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        "I don't understand that command"}
```

Question: how this code understands if start or stop is entered second time, if started variable is assigned to False value manually?

Comment: The code is in a loop, so imagine everything inside of `while True` executing over and over again.

Comment: Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop#Python